# Comparison of 2 multimeters

Tags: discussion

Can I ask a question about which one of two multimeters would be better to buy or it will be closed? I don't want a comparison between a lot of them as it would be opinion-based but just between 2 of them.

Comment: Adam, you would be better off if you take this question to our excellent [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), at least for pre-screening.  I appreciate that you asked here before posting to the main board.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I am a long time user of the Stack sites so I know how things work :P I have never used the chat thought, so I don't really know how :P

Comment: [EE.SE Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be okay, but be specific about what you are asking. For example, are there certain specs that you don't know how to interpret? Do you have a specific kind of project in mind that might require a specialized DMM?

If you just ask "which one is better?", the answer will be "Read the specs for each and see which one meets your need for a lower price".

Even if you ask, "how often will I need a capacitance measurement function?" that's an opinion or anecdote based question and the answer depends entirely what kind of project you work on.

Comment: Thanks I will try to make it a good one although no matter what people will always find an excuse to downvote in here... :P